# Windows Authentication Doesn't automatically grab user credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, active-directory, single-sign-on

I have an aspx site that I'm working on for our company's intranet. I recently added some secure pages that require the user to be a member of particular groups in an Active Directory in order to view. We are using Windows Authentication for the site(I have windows authentication in the .config). Windows Authentication is enabled in the IIS, and Anonymous Authentication is disabled. I've also enabled NTLM Authentication in the projects properties.

As far as I can tell, the security stuff is working as expected. Only users with the proper credentials can access the secure pages (I'm securing them with the [Authenticate Roles = "bla"] check on the controller action).

The problem I'm having is not really a problem, but more of an annoyance. Whenever the user logs in to the site, they are prompted with a login dialog. I don't want this. I want the site to grab their credentials from the windows login and use that to determine their access rights.  I was under the impression that Windows Authentication handled this on its own, but it appears I was wrong.

Basically, how can I get rid of the login prompt and have Windows Authentication handle all of that same functionality automatically?

Is there some server setting I might need to change? Could it be something in my code?

I want it to work with at least IE, Firefox, and Chrome, if that is at all possible.

***Update 7/23/2012

Thanks everyone for the suggestions, unfortunately I still haven't gotten this to work properly. Some things I've noticed that may help provide some more details

- I'm fairly certain the intranet site is on our list of "trusted" sites (our network admin says it is).
- I'm using NTLM authentication and NTLM authentication only. If I remove NTLM authentication and enable Negotiate: Kerberos authentication, I just get a 401 - Unauthorized error. I can fix this by disabling Kernel mode authentication, but then I still get the credentials prompt(which I don't want).
- If I check "Enable Integrated Windows Authentication*" in IE > Internet Options > Advanced > Security, it will prompt me for credentials, but entering my credentials no longer works. It will ask me three times and then take me to the 401 error page.
- IE9 asks me only for my password and pulls my username(good). Chrome and Firefox prompt me for username and password.

Comment: I understand if it asks for user credentials under Firefox, Chrome at least once but are you saying that IE is also prompting for user credentials?

Comment: Yes, currently all 3 browsers request the user's credentialsl

Comment: You should clean up your question.  Most of the backstory isn't required.  You also have three seperate questions, 2 of them can be combined into the first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in Internet Explorer / Tools / Options / Advanced.

There is a checkbox "Enable Integrated Windows Authentication" under "Security".

Is this checked?

It's checked by default, and can be set by admins using a GPO:

http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/configuring-advanced-ie-settings-using-group-policy.html

Comment: Yes, "Enable Integrated Windows Authentication*" is checked.

Comment: Additionally the site url must be added manually to local intranet zone in ie.

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla, do you mean in IE go to Tools > Internet Options > Security > Sites > Advanced > Add ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting within IE that allows this automatic pass through to happen. Your system administrator could create a group policy and push this to all users.

I've also been successful in configuring Firefox to function in the same matter but that would involve modifying individual users FF configurations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are you talking about a setting that can be enabled when you click the "Custom Level.." button in Tools > Internet Options > Security ?

Answer (score 0):

This line should be in your web.config within the `<system.web>` element.

`<authentication mode="Windows" />`

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd provide an update as to what actually solved the problem.

I tried all of the great suggestions you guys provided for internet explorer settings, but in the end, it turned out to be a server setting.

Flipping the order of Providers for the site to NTLM, Negotiate in that order solved the problem.

Comment: Richard, would you please add something more in your answer?